# RTL text (Hebrew) shows reversed when is on SVG path

Tags: svg, text, path, right-to-left

I cant show properly RTL text on a curved path in SVG.
Tried [This Codepan](https://codepen.io/tagtag/pen/jKerRx) 
but cant make it show properly
Tried adding direction, writing-mode,dir,override- bidi - nothing works
Is there a way to do that without reversing the address bytes of the text or the points of the path ? In future I plan to use Eng/Heb mixture so dont really want to reverse the text instead

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/textPath -->


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 22.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 177.5 175" xml:space="preserve">
<defs>
    <pattern id="image" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="200" width="200">
      <image x="0" y="0" xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/7Nlcay7.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  
 <ellipse id="FillThisWithColorOrPattern" fill="url(#image)" stroke="#333333" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="90" cy="87" rx="87.5" ry="82"/>
<circle id="Inner_1_" fill="#FF0000" cx="90" cy="87" r="35"/>
 <path id="TextLine1_Path" fill=None        
  d="M90,137.5c-27.8,0-50.5-22.7-50.5-50.5S62.2,36.5,90,36.5s50.5,22.7,50.5,50.5S117.8,137.5,90,137.5z M90,37.5
  c-27.3,0-49.5,22.2-49.5,49.5s22.2,49.5,49.5,49.5c27.3,0,49.5-22.2,49.5-49.5S117.3,37.5,90,37.5z"/>
   <text stroke="#00FF00">
    <textPath xlink:href="#TextLine1_Path">
     שלום כיתה אלף
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: @Robert: thanks, checked on Chrome,Firefox,Safari - all three both on MacOs and iOS. Same behavior, which is a relief, since it is probably a bug in my code. I count on this feature with my new site and it has to be fully browser/platform compatible

Comment: I think what you saw is FireFox just interpretting differently the start angle and the text looks differently. I tried many times, even downloaded FireFox for ios ..

Comment: OK in that case you can force it to be left to right if you need to via unicode-bidi="bidi-override" direction="ltr". Is that what you're looking for. I'm not sure why you'd want that though.

Comment: You haven't written it back to front in the markup have you? What is it supposed to mean in English? Displaying as a textPath displays the same ordering as any other as text as far as I can see.

Comment: Thanks for your time, Robert. In English it says "Hello First Grade" ( like the school greeting). I wrote it as it is getting written in the original language , right to left : שלום כיתה אלף. While on the textPath is shows mirrored. Interesting fact : if you just show it as a plain text inside SVG ( not on path ) - it will be shown properly !

Comment: it looks to be in the same direction to me textPath or not textPath. Clearer if you draw the textPath on a horizontal line i.e. on d="M100,30h300". Maybe editing your question would make it easier to see what issue you're experiencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this is a bug in the rendering app/lib. As Bi-direction and shaping of complex language scripts is a visual issue and it is not a logical one with SVG language/standard itself.

Anyway, things changed from the time question was posted. As currently Dec 2021, using Mac OS 11.6.1:

- Firefox/95.0 renders it fine.
- Inkscape/1.1-alpha renders it fine.
- Chromium/90.0 renders it reversed and unshaped (non-connected letters).
- Safari/15.1 renders it reversed and unshaped (non-connected letters).

Answer (score 1):

in 2023, this is fixed in chrome, but broken in safari. my solution was to hardcode reverse the string AND do unicode-bidi="bidi-override" direction="ltr". see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75411819/664456