# Hebrew text on SVG textPath reversed only in Safari

Tags: svg, safari, cross-browser, right-to-left, hebrew

When putting Hebrew text on an SVG textPath it is reversed only in Safari (macOS ventura 13.2 Safari 16.3). It is OK in Firefox and Chrome. Text that is NOT on a path is always OK. Furthermore, I am able to use bidi-override to reverse the text in Firefox/Chrome, but in Safari that did not un-reverse the reversed text as I expected (and even if it did that would not be a cross-browser solution). I also tried playing with various rtl/ltr css/html/svg dir/direction settings as well as lang/xml:lang he. I can of course reverse the text string in advance for Safari, but I am looking for a cross-browser solution.

This is a similar question, but the author is not addressing the browser-specific issue (I think at the time it was also broken in Chrome so he could just reverse the string in advance for both), and the accepted answer is not offering a concrete explanation nor is it helpful practically: [RTL text (Hebrew) shows reversed when is on SVG path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51085826/rtl-text-hebrew-shows-reversed-when-is-on-svg-path)

**Chrome**:
[image: Chrome]

**Safari:**
[image: Safari]

```html
<html dir="rtl" lang="he">
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" width=500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path
    id="MyPath1"
    fill="none"
    stroke="red"
    d="M 500, 120 m 0, -110 a 110,110 0 0,1 0,320 a 110,110 0 0,1 0,-320" />
<path
    id="MyPath2"
    fill="none"
    stroke="green"
    d="M 200, 120 m 0, -110 a 110,110 0 0,1 0,320 a 110,110 0 0,1 0,-320" />
    
  <text x='600' y='200'>
    text not on path is ok טקסט רגיל
  </text>
  <text>
    <textPath href="#MyPath1" text-anchor="end">hebrew textpath reversed only on safari טקסט על מסלול הפוך רק בספארי</x>
  </text>
  <text unicode-bidi="bidi-override" direction="ltr">
    <textPath href="#MyPath2">טקסט על מסלול הפוך תמיד hebrew textpath always reversed</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>

</html>
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/eyaler/pen/VwBBOXz?editors=1011

Comment: Report it as a [webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/) if it's not already reported.

Answer (score 2):

Got it! Since Safari is just ignoring all bidi stuff on textPath, that is, both the logical direction and the bidi-override, I can just reverse the string in advance AND do unicode-bidi="bidi-override" direction="ltr"! Double negatives to the rescue! This is a cross-browser solution.

```html
<html dir="rtl" lang="he">
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" width=500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path
    id="MyPath1"
    fill="none"
    stroke="red"
    d="M 500, 120 m 0, -110 a 110,110 0 0,1 0,320 a 110,110 0 0,1 0,-320" />
<path
    id="MyPath2"
    fill="none"
    stroke="green"
    d="M 200, 120 m 0, -110 a 110,110 0 0,1 0,320 a 110,110 0 0,1 0,-320" />
    
  <text x='600' y='200'>
    text not on path is ok טקסט רגיל
  </text>
  <text>
    <textPath href="#MyPath1" text-anchor="end">hebrew textpath reversed only on safari טקסט על מסלול הפוך רק בספארי</x>
  </text>
  <text unicode-bidi="bidi-override" direction="ltr">
    <textPath href="#MyPath2">רדסב גצומו רוקמב יתכפהש לולסמ לע טסקט hebrew textpath hardcoded reversed to display ok on all browsers</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>

</html>
```